# MySQL - Duplicate Entry Error on Empty Table

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am attempting to insert records into a MySQL database via my Java application (JPA/EclipseLink).  I am getting back this error when inserting into a table that has a two column primary key (CM_MAC_ADDRESS adn CHANGE_ID):

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'BATCH1-AA:BB:CC:DD' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO CONVERGENCE.MODEM (CBS_ACCOUNT_ID, CM_IP, DX_SERVICE_LEVEL, IS_PILOT, MODEL, CM_MAC_ADDRESS, CHANGE_ID, OPTICAL_RECEIVER_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [8 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Change ID=BATCH1, CM MAC=AA:BB:CC:DD)
```

The weird thing is, this table is empty:

```
mysql> select * from MODEM;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So there's no way that it could be a duplicate key.  Why else would this error be thrown?

Comment: could this happen if you do multiple inserts and then commit them all at once?

Comment: Yes, we are inserting multiple records, but I triple checked that each of them had a different CM_MAC_ADDRESS, so the primary keys should be unique.

Comment: Found the issue where the same primary key was being set as a foreign key in two records.